# please explain this c++ syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

could someone please explain the syntax of the following snippet from a c++ class template?

```
public:
explicit Foo(size_t ratio = 500)
    :list(Bar<I>())
    ,vec(Bar<iterator>())
    ,n(0), r(ratio){}
```

I have decent experience with programming and understand most concepts but the syntax behind this is just so foreign to me, i can't understand it. `I` is the generic type. Specifically, I'm not sure what the explicit is doing here, in addition to what is going on when one would execute some code such as `Foo<int> myfoo;`.

thanks!

Comment: This answers the what is explicit nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: You need [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1). Please select more than one.

Answer (score 4):

The `explicit` keyword makes sure that your constructor is not picked as part as a user-defined conversion sequence to perform implicit conversions when copy-initialized with a value of type `size_t`.

Without the `explicit` keyword, for instance, all of the following would be valid:

```
Foo<int> bar(Foo<int> f) 
{ 
    return 0; // OK
}

Foo<int> f = 1729; // OK
bar(42); // OK
```

Declaring your constructor as `explicit` prevents the initializations above from compiling.

---

What follows the constructor's signature is an [**initialization list**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html), and it is used to construct the base class subobjects and data member subobjects of your class before the body of your constructor is entered.

When you do *not* use an initialization list, the data members of your class are default-constructed. This, however, may not be an option if your class has `const` data members, or data members of reference type, or data members of a class type which do not have a default constructor.

Comment: Now, what is `:list`, `Bar<I>`, `,n(0),`, and `r(ratio){}`? Wanna write a book? :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: Nobody would publish it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor for the class `Foo`, but I'm sure you already knew that.

`explicit` says that this constructor must receive an argument of `size_t`. That is, one cannot pass in anything that would be implicitly casted to a type `size_t` (ex: `int`).

The rest of the things are part of the constructor's `initializer list`, which means the constructor initializes the data member `list` with `Bar<I>()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of a constructor for `Foo`. The constructor is `explicit`, which means that it won't be involved in implicit conversions. As an example consider:

```
void bar(Foo);
bar(10); // Error - would require an implicit conversion
```

Marking a constructor as `explicit` prevents such conversions.

Everything after the `:` is a member initialization list. It lists members of `Foo` by their names and the parentheses contain the expressions with which to initialize them. For example, `list` will be initialized with the temporary object created by `Bar<I>()`, `n` is initialized with `0`, etc.